# Unable to connect Visual Studio to correct server after fresh SQL Server Express install

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016-express

I had a bunch of old/conflicting named instances of SQL Server on my machine, so I deleted them and decided to create a fresh default instance of SQL Server 2016 Express.

Which created myriad problems...

First, I tried running my migrations in my code and I got an error

> Unable to Add Data Connection. Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc

After a full day of searching and downloading the Shared Management Objects from the 2016 and 2014 feature packs (to no avail), I finally tried downloading it from the 2012 feature pack (as suggested in some small comment somewhere) and that did the trick - I could finally create a data connection in Server Explorer!

But now...I still cannot seem to connect to the right server. In Server Explorer, the server is listed, but no tables appear. I also cannot run my migrations. I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Here is Server Explorer in Visual Studio:

[(Server Explorer in Visual Studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njfUN.jpg)

This is my connection string in my `app.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=EFChallenge2; integrated security=SSPI" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, SSMS connects to the server just fine. I can create databases and tables with no problem.

I named the new default instance of SQL Server Express `JenProWin`, the same as it was previously named. Could Visual Studio be referring to an old named instance with the same name? If so, how can I update it?  (NOTE: I've already tried deleting the server and adding it again - the issue remains.)

Comment: Hello Jenergy, please try giving different instance name. That might help if your previous version is not uninstalled completely.

Comment: It ended up being a problem with the SQL Server Agent - I noticed that the service wasn't running and wouldn't start, no matter what I did. I did another full, fresh install of SQL Server and everything works perfectly now!

Comment: I am glad you are able to solve it. Happy coding :)